# How can i show image name i get from backend instead of no file chosen in react js

Tags: reactjs, image, redux, path

I already have image path and image name that i get from python backend. And i stored it globally using redux. How i can **show that name instead of no file chosen** in an **img** tag?

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind that dynamic name in the place of "no file chosen" and you have to add it on condition basis. if file is already selected then dynamic name will be shown otherwise "No file chosen" will be show. You can set the selected file in state or redux whatever you feel comfortable.

Hope this will help. For more explanation please share you code